# Duplicate Records in Database

Tags: java, oracle

I am having this problem for the last two projects that i worked on. Both of the projects are written in Java and use Oracle 11g as DB. When i look at the code there is nothing wrong in transaction management etc. The flow is very simple and like this in code.

```
Connection con = null;
try {
   //Get connection
   //Run validation
   //Insert record
   //Commit
} catch() {
   //Rollback
} finally {
   //Close connection
}
```

The validation part checks for some business rules and prevents dublicate entries.

### 1.st case

This works fine when a user calls this part of code fully and commits the current transaction, only after that another user comes. In this case when another user wants to run this code because that the other transaction committed the changes validation part can see the record and prevents duplicate.

But when two user runs the same code at the same time sometimes duplicate records occurs. The flow is like below and i have no idea how to handle it. I've looked at isolation levels etc but none of them works for this case. The only one applicable is using unique constraint but it is not suitable for the projects.

- user1 passes validation
- user2 passes validation
- user1 insert record
- user2 insert record

### 2.nd case

Another case is totaly bizarre and i can't reproduce it in my tests but i witnessed it in production. When the system load is high the system creates duplicate records on a single click of a user. That means the user presses the button only one time but the system creates multiple records at the background. These records have different ids but nearly exact creation times and all the other values are the same.

We thought initially that when the system load is high the application server couldn't handle it properly (because it was an old unsopperted one) and because it happened rarely we leave it there. But after sometime later we ha to change the application server to another one for another reason and the problem persist. And the second project i mentioned has a totaly different application server.

I and two different team worked on these problems for weeks but we couldn't find a suitable solution for these two cases and we couldn't even find the reason for the second one. Any help would be welcome if you guys encountered something like this or know the solution.

Comment: for the 1. case, is it not allowed for ALL users, not to run this code simultaneously? Or is there some kind of condition for it?

Comment: Why is a constraint "not suitable for the project"?  If you wanted to enforce this through the application, a session would need to lock some resource before doing the validation that would prevent any other session from doing that same validation.  That's certainly possible in Java though I'm hard'pressed to guess why that would be "suitable" while a more efficient constraint would not be.

Comment: @JustinCave It is not suitable because this is a product we sell to multiple customers and some wants uniqueness on the field and some doesn't. A lock on the resources is not suitable either because there is no resource exists before we are inserting new data hene we can't row lock so we should lock the whole table which is not so good.

Comment: @JohnnyAW i didn't understand exactly what you are asking. Think this as an enrollment method. All the users can and should run simultaneously.

Comment: then simply synchronize the validation-method

Comment: @JohnnyAW okay i will try that thanks, what about the second case thou?

Comment: @eakyurek wait, you probably need to synchronize validation + insert-Methods. Create a `ReentrantLock` for it and `lock` it before validation and `unlock` after insert-method. 2. case could have multiple causes

Comment: @JohnnyAW i was thinking about locking the whole block

Comment: @eakyurek sure, if it's Ok for you

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use Synchronization on an object to avoid duplicates. Probably the RUN VALIDATION block might be a good candidate for fixing this but it really depends on your application logic.
2. It has nothing to do with your Webserver you need to use an Idempotent HTTP method to submit your form.

Comment: I will try synchronization for the first case it looks like a good option but i didn't understand exactly what you mean by idempotent method, can you explain it further. As far as i see POST is not an idempotent method but GET is. Is it okay to send the form with GET and will it solve the probem?

Comment: idempotent means you don't change your state, no matter how many times you execute the same request. For GET-requests it's obviously not a problem, since GET shouldn't change DB. For POST you can try to check, if you already executed this request, e.g. perform your validation method

Comment: @JohnnyAW It is checking if this request was executed before in validation part but like i said because it is not committed it sees it as not executed. I think synchronize will solve this issue as well but i am really curious why in the first place it acts like multiple request.

Comment: @eakyurek : looks like all you need is to fix the validation() method.

Comment: @Geek by fix you mean synchronize? because it is working as intended only it can't see uncommitted stuff naturally.

Comment: I can't be sure it depends on your application logic. You should ideally synchronize the smallest piece of code and in worst case synchronize all. You will have to see what suits best for you.

Comment: @eakyurek if you lock your Lock before validation and unlock it after commit, you should see the "uncommitted stuff", since you would wait until everything will be committed

Comment: @JohnnyAW like i said above i will try that :) but i still don't know what is the cause.

Comment: @eakyurek : I like Johny's comment.. just to do defensive testing lock all your methods by one lock and try to reproduce the issue.. You should not be able to reproduce either 1 or 2.  However this is will be bad for performance.